# in react TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error " TypeError: Cannot read property destroy of null "

[image]

this the code where get the error. I don't know where it went wrong.

[image]

need help on this.

Comment: Under `componentWillUnmount` `console.log(this.ps)` see what it log ( must not be `null` ) ?

Comment: make sure this.ps is not null in your if statement before you destroy it